# Help, after updating my Joomla to 3.9.1 the Slider (Avatar Articles Nivo) is not displaying anymore

Tags: joomla-3.x, helix3

I can display / hide the title of the module, but the slider is not showing up anymore...

HELP Template used = Helix Ultimate (newest version, cache also deleted)

Comment: All good, for anybody interested, the System - Dj-JQueryMonster Plugin made it reappear; probably a jquery conflict issue due to the update

Comment: You should put the resolution in the Answer box below and then accept the answer as correct. Putting the solution in the Comments doesn't really let anyone know you have fixed your issue and it will leave it as yet another unsolved issue.

Comment: Cheers @Irata, I'm still quite new to this forum

Comment: now you should see an option there to Accept the answer and that will mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All good, for anybody interested, the System - Dj-JQueryMonster Plugin made it reappear; probably a jquery conflict issue due to the update